# Hreflang, alternate y canonical

Tags: html, seo

Tengo un sitio web en el cual cuenta con dos versiones :

http://www.example.com/ :

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/" />
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Y la url http://www.example.com/en/ :

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

Se que estoy armando mal las etiquetas, pero no logro entender la logica que sigue el alternate/canonical/hreflang para un marcado correcto para el SEO. En este caso, ¿Como tendria que afrontar mejor el marcado? ¿Basta con hacerlo en el sitemap.xml para los buscadores? Ejm.:

```
...
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc> 
    <xhtml:link
        rel="canonical"
        hreflang="es"
        href="http://www.example.com/"
    />
    <xhtml:link
        rel="alternate"
        hreflang="en"
        href="http://www.example.com/en/"
    />
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/en/</loc> 
    <xhtml:link
        rel="canonical"
        hreflang="es"
        href="http://www.example.com/"
    />
    <xhtml:link
        rel="alternate"
        hreflang="en"
        href="http://www.example.com/en/"
    />
</url>
...
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien a qué te refieres. ¿No pones por qué crees que están mal las etiquetas? Por otro lado deberías de usarlo coherentemente en las etiquetas link y a, tanto en el html de las páginas como en el sitemap.

Comment: Perdón, con las malas prisas no me exprese con claridad. A mi modo de entender están correctas, pero en https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/hreflang/ me dice lo siguiente:
 
**Alternate URL has a non-self-referencing canonical tag** y de eso nace mi inseguridad.

Answer (score 2):

Según yo entiendo este tema no necesitas usar canonical en este caso, `rel=canonical` es para evitar contenido duplicado, por ejemplo cuando diferentes URL apuntan en realidad a la misma página, típico en la página de inicio::

- www.example.com
- example.com
- example.com/index.html

En tu caso que tienes idiomas distintos, por tanto el contenido es diferente, no te haría falta. Por otra parte no tienes que poner `hreflang` en el canonical.

Si usas canonical la url tiene que coincidir con la de alternate:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/en/" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Según mi experiencia como SEO:

1-Las metas mejor ponerlas en la cabecera del html, aunque puedes ponerlas en el sitemap,este archivo es un mapa del sitio web, es ahí donde tendras que poner los enlaces internos de tu paginas, hay varias webs que te hacen el sitemap.xml si no utilizas wordpress. En el sitemap lo tendrias que poner de esta manera por cada url que quisieras añadir con hreflang:

```
  <url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/english/</loc>
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="de"
             href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/"
             />
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="de-ch"
             href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/"
             />
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="en"
             href="http://www.example.com/english/"
             />
</url>
```

2- Las metas de hreflang es para decirle a Google que esa Url es para ese idioma o esa región, y así Google nos la posiciona en ese idioma.

Este sería el ejemplo perfecto de una meta en la cabecera del HTMLque es donde se suele colocar habitualmente.

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />`

3-Si tienes varias URL alternativas dirigidas a usuarios del mismo idioma, pero con distinta configuración regional. Especificamos la Url para cada región que queramos y luego para las demás regiones ponemos la Url en ingles genérico.

Para ello esto tendríamos que hacerlo así:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ie" hreflang="en-ie" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ca" hreflang="en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-au" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en" />
```

Lo mas habitual es poner estas meta en las cabecera de html en el `<head></head>`

Lo de canonical es como ha comentado Blonfu es para indicar que si tenemos contenido duplicado la url principal es la que le indicamos. Nunca deberíamos de tener contenido duplicado en nuestra web.