# Implementar de forma correcta rel=alternate, rel=canonical y rel=amphtml

Tags: html, seo, amp

Me estoy volviendo loco para intentar entender cómo debería implementar estas etiquetas para no marear a Google con lo que tiene que indexar y lo que no. El caso es que tengo una sección de noticias con una versión AMP. Además, algunas de estas noticias tienen también una versión en inglés.

Si tengo una noticia en castellano e inglés, tengo puesto lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost/xboxone/es/noticia/777/Deals-With-Gold-y-ofertas-Spotlight-de-Xbox-One-y-Xbox-360-hasta-el-15-de-mayo-de-2018/">
<link rel="amphtml" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost/xboxone/es/noticia/777/Deals-With-Gold-y-ofertas-Spotlight-de-Xbox-One-y-Xbox-360-hasta-el-15-de-mayo-de-2018/amp/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost/xboxone/en/news/777/Xbox-One-and-Xbox-360-Deals-With-Gold-and-Spotlight-Sales-until-may-15/">
<link rel="amphtml" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost/xboxone/en/news/777/Xbox-One-and-Xbox-360-Deals-With-Gold-and-Spotlight-Sales-until-may-15/amp/">
```

Cuando entro a la versión AMP de la noticia en castellano por ejemplo (con versión NO AMP y versión en inglés), uso lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost/xboxone/es/noticia/777/Deals-With-Gold-y-ofertas-Spotlight-de-Xbox-One-y-Xbox-360-hasta-el-15-de-mayo-de-2018/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost/xboxone/en/news/777/Xbox-One-and-Xbox-360-Deals-With-Gold-and-Spotlight-Sales-until-may-15/">
```

¿Sería correcto? Los ejemplos que dan en la página de AMP y Google no habla de casos en los que tienes versión AMP, estándar y una versión en otro idioma. Es un tema parecido a [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21907/hreflang-alternate-y-canonical).

Comment: [Esto te podría interesar](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). **Ya Google no recomienda el uso de `canonical`**, por razones de simplicidad a decir de ellos mismos. Puedes leer [también aquí](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) y sacar tus propias conclusiones. En cuanto a [`amp`, puedes ver esto](https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/internationalization/).

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por el aporte. Me ha quedado más claro con el enlace de AMP que has facilitado. He analizado los ejemplos que tiene y he decidido quitar el `hreflang` de las rel='amphtml'. En las versiones AMP he incluido la URL canónica ya las alternativas. Al menos es lo que tienen puesto en este ejemplo. https://ampbyexample.com/internationalization/alternate/

Comment: @A.Cedano esa recomendación es para páginas multilingües, pero parece que para otros casos siguen recomendando canonical (p.e. para versión móvil o de escritorio)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no podría hablarte con propiedad, puesto que no estoy empapado del tema (por eso referí a los enlaces directamente). No obstante, la afirmación de Google es esta (en el 1er enlace de mi anterior comentario: *Update: to simplify implementation, we no longer recommend using `rel=canonical`.* ... No especifican si es sólo para un cierto tipo de dispositivo.

Comment: Yo tampoco, pero parecen seguir recomendando canonical [en otros artículos](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) (en la sección de directrices generales) sí se indica algo sobre el canonical en el mismo idioma: "_Especifica una página canónica en el mismo idioma o, en el caso de que una página no esté disponible en ese idioma, selecciona el que consideres más adecuado_". Por eso no sé si la recomendación del primer enlace es sólo para páginas multilingües.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo ayudar con el **canonical**

Este es para evitar contenido duplicado. Entonces, si vos tenés un sitio que solo está en AMP, en cada página debería poner la URL actual.
Pero, si tenés un sitio que según un parámetro, responde con amp o responde sin amp (este es un claro ejemplo de sitios de noticias que para se indexados tienen la versión básica del artículo en amp, pero lo que muestran realmente no es con AMP sino cargada de JS y demás) entonces en la versión con amp, en el canonical podrás le URL del artículo sin amp, para que Google, cuando responda, muestre la versión "completa"

**En Resumen - Canonical**

Objetivo: evitar contenido duplicado y ser penalizado por papá Google

- Si solo AMP: El canonical tendrá la url actual
- Si convives con AMP: El canonical apuntará al sitio sin AMP